# How to get arr[arr[i]] from a list using Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

Edit 1:
Can I rewrite this code using LINQ?
Assuming the list contains values between [0,N-1] where N = size of the array.

```
List<int> list = new List<int>(){2, 3, 0, 1, 4};
for(int i =0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
  list[i] = list[i] * list.Count + list[list[i]];           
}
```

Comment: How would you expect this to work? LINQ Is not designed to update the collection it is iterating.  That is precisely why you need to use a for loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously, LINQ was not created to update anything (Q in the abbreviation), but there`s is **Select** method, which allow you to do similar.

```
var result = list.Select(item => item * list.Count + list[item]);
```

That way you will query your data into new form, what is not update, but creating new object with separate values.